# Issue using PostgreSQL - db:create flags error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

I'm trying to setup a new rails app using pg. The gem installs but when I run `rails db:create` I get this error in my terminal:

```
Specified 'postgresql' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded. Add `gem 'pg'` to your Gemfile (and ensure its version is at the minimum required by ActiveRecord).
    Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"postgresql", "pool"=>5, "timeout"=>5000, "database"=>"db/spaces_development"}
    rails aborted!
    Gem::LoadError: Specified 'postgresql' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded. Add `gem 'pg'` to your Gemfile (and ensure its version is at the minimum required by ActiveRecord).
```

This is my Gemfile & database.yml has anyone got any idea's what I'm doing wrong?

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

git_source(:github) do |repo_name|
  repo_name = "#{repo_name}/#{repo_name}" unless repo_name.include?("/")
  "https://github.com/#{repo_name}.git"
end

ruby '2.4.1'
# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.1.2'
# Use Postgress for database
gem 'pq',
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.7'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 3.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
  gem 'better_errors'
  gem 'capybara-email'
  #gem 'capybara-webkit'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
  gem 'ffaker'
  gem 'database_cleaner'
  gem 'letter_opener'
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'pry'
  gem 'pry-nav'
  gem 'pry-rails', '~> 0.3.2'
  gem 'simple_bdd'
  gem 'shoulda-matchers'
  gem 'spring'
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

datbase.yml

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  timeout: 5000

development:
  <<: *default
  database: db/spaces_development

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  <<: *default
  database: db/spaces_test

production:
  <<: *default
  database: db/spaces_production
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typo: `gem 'pq',` is what you have in your gemfile while it should be `gem 'pg'`

Also, don't forget to run `bundle install` to make sure the gem is installed and ready to rock & roll

Comment: Thanks. Silly mistake... it's been a long day.